# SynchronizingObject vs. Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface, timer

In my form's class, I've added a method to "fade" it out. This makes use of `System.Timers.Timer` and the `Elapsed` event uses a delegate to change the form's opacity. This was the code:

```
public void FadeOut()
{
    // Timer for transition
    Timer fade = new Timer();

    // Transition code
    fade.Elapsed += delegate
    {
        this.Opacity += 0.05;

        if (this.Opacity >= .95)
        {
            this.Opacity = 1;
            fade.Enabled = false;
            fade.Dispose();
        }
    };

    fade.Interval = 100;
    fade.Enabled = true;
}
```

This caused a "Cross-thread operation not valid" error, which is a common hurdle I see. So I looked around for solutions and the first ones to come up involved using `.BeginInvoke` and blocks of code to keep the call to the same thread as the control. But I found this looked really bulky, so I kept looking and then discovered the `SynchronizingObject` property of `System.Timers.Timer`. This seems better because it only needed one extra line of code:

```
// Timer for transition
Timer fade = new Timer();
fade.SynchronizingObject = this;
```

The code runs fine now. But I'm really confused, how come a lot of solutions are suggesting the use of `BeginInvoke/Invoke` when all that's needed is to set `SynchronizingObject` to the form control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I believe that the Timer will internally use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` as well on the `SynchronizingObject` property.

Let us say that this property just gives some abstraction to the developer; to make his life easier.

My guess was indeed correct, this is what Reflector tells us about the `MyTimerCallback` private member method of `System.Timers.Timer`:

```
 ElapsedEventHandler onIntervalElapsed = this.onIntervalElapsed;
 if (onIntervalElapsed != null)
 {
     if ((this.SynchronizingObject != null) && this.SynchronizingObject.InvokeRequired)
     {
         this.SynchronizingObject.BeginInvoke(onIntervalElapsed, new object[] { this, e });
     }
     else
     {
         onIntervalElapsed(this, e);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ah, so this handles the dirty work for the developer? tis' clearer now. I guess it's a new thing. Thank you for the background!

Answer (score 3):

Mostly because it is pointless to use the property.  Yes, it ensures that the Elapsed event handler runs on the UI thread.  But now it just does the same thing as a System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

Not quite though, it is worse.  Because it doesn't guarantee that Elapsed won't be called after you disable it.  Disabling it doesn't flush any pending invokes nor TP threads that aren't ready to run yet.  There could be hundreds if the Interval is small compared to the amount of work done by the handler.

You absolutely want a System.Windows.Forms.Timer here.  You are not doing any useful work on the threadpool thread.

Comment: As stated in one comment, I thought using a Timer control would be bulkier, but now that you've explained this it makes better sense. Thank you for the advice, I'll switch to Forms.Timer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [WinForms timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)? This is based on window messages and will always run in the UI thread; since you want to perform updates where the UI thread needs to pump messages anyways this may be a better solution (no synchronization/blocking required).

Comment: Hmm, I thought using a Timer control would be a little bit bulkier, but that's actually a very good point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Timer solutions like this are really a bit of a hack.

You'd be better off writing a proper asynchronous thread and doing the callback either with 
BeginInvoke or [SynchronizationContext](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SyncContextTutorial.aspx).

As you rightly observe, it's far from a one-liner, but multi-tasking, done properly, never is.

Answer (score 0):

The point is the SCOPE of code. The whole event handler? or just the UI changing code.

timer.SynchronizingObject make the event handler to be called on the thread of given object. If you set this to 'this' in 'Form1' class, This means that all of your code for processing timer event is run by that same thread of 'Form1' instance even though you created a thread based timer.  So this does NOTHING. SAME as windows form timer.

The reason you want to do this is because you want to access UI controls and make some changes in Form1, but the whole UI hangs if you use windows form timer. Because they all get executed on the same thread.

To avoid this, you use a threading based timer. Your event handler is called on another thread that comes from some system thread pool. This solves the problem of hanging UI. However, this brings up another problem. Cross-thread accessing UI controls exception. On some versions of Visual Studio, you can disable this checking on debug builds. But there is no way you can just bypass this checking on release builds. This thread checking is just by design to safeguard from crashes caused by multi-threading. THEN you need to use all those invoke and delegation stuff.

The important part here is that it is the only few lines of code that is redirected to be run on the Form1 thread. Not the whole event handler. Most of the event handling code is run on another thread. And that includes code like doing something on network or disk.

This makes the DIFFERENCE.

BUT, all these apply to windows form apps only. For WPF, just use dispatcher timer. (This is why you cannot find Windows.Threading in WinForm because you can't used dispatcher timer in WinForm, but available in WPF)